# Why is Stack Overflow icon distorted and blurry on Tweet message?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, twitter

When you click on the [Twitter icon](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=%2Fcities&via=StackDevJobs&text=Browse%20featured%20companies%20and%20developer%20jobs%20in%20these%20thriving%20tech%20hubs%20around%20the%20world%20http%3A%2F%2Fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2Fcities) (top-left under SO Careers logo) of the "[Explore Cities](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities)" page, you will be shown a page with a tweet automatically pre-populated in the textbox for "What’s happening?". At the bottom of that page, you will see a "New to Twitter?" section along with a Stack Overflow icon as shown in the below screenshot:

> [image]

Stack Overflow icon looks distorted and blurry on the current background color. Whereas, here is how the Stack Overflow icon looks on the official "[Logos and Icons](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos)" download page:

[image]

Also, the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) clearly says: "Do not distort or alter our logo in any way".

I am not sure why a scaled down SO icon gets blurry on the Tweet page but definitely needs a better version of the same. Can it be fixed with a crisp and clear icon?

Comment: Looks like a border was added to the edges. In other words, ...it's *not* the SO logo.

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything we can actually do. Twitter compresses and resizes uploaded images to optimize for content delivery. Facebook makes icons just as blurry, although their system at least doesn't add the ugly black coloring to it. The icon on the [StackDevJobs](https://twitter.com/StackDevJobs) page looks a lot better than that resized one.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I removed the border from #promo.thumbnail img and still the same.

Comment: @animuson yes, I agree. The SO icon on StackDevJobs page us way better than this Tweet message page. The only difference I see here is the StackDevJobs page icon natural size is 73x73 px but shown as 48x48 px. Whereas, Tweet page icon natural size is 48x48 px and I think this where the compress and resize (as pointed by you) gone bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two problems with the image.

1. The background should be white to make it stand out. The current image background is transparent, making the image blend into the background. Changing the background to white fixes this. This could be something for Twitter to do, but if not, SE could change it.
2. The image is blurry indeed. If you replace that image with the image from the [StackDevJobs](https://twitter.com/StackDevJobs) page it looks better already (still a little blurry due to resizing).

> [image: ss]

Comment: +1 Patrick good find and it seems like the background color can't be change. I found another possibility added in my answer.

Comment: Your answer solves the original question. I will keep my answer as an alternative for using an official SO Careers icon.

Answer (score 2):

I spent good amount of time in reading Twitter's help page but couldn't find any information about customizing "pre-populated tweet textbox". All I could find was "[Customizing your design](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15357)" theme for the Tweet detail pages.

It seems like the issue is at the Twitter's end as SE is uploading the quality PNG icon image but Twitter compresses and resizes uploaded images to optimize for content delivery (Source: ♦ moderator animuson comment under my post).

Apart from what Patrick Hofman has suggested in his answer, the another possibility (assuming that SE can't change the background-color of Tweet textbox) is using the official Stack Overflow Careers icon as suggested in the "[Logos and Icons](https://stackexchange.com/about/logos)":

> [image]

The "[StackDevJobs](https://twitter.com/StackDevJobs)" profile is the official Twitter account dedicated for "[Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)" (profile URL points to SO Careers) and Stack Exchange UI/UX design team have created an icon specifically for Stack Overflow Careers (as shown in the above screenshot), we could upload this icon instead of the current one.

Here is how it looks upon changing it to Stack Overflow Careers icon:

> [image]